# Кое-что не понимаю в маленькой функции pow(x,n)

Tags: javascript

Вот задание : Напишите функцию pow(x,n) , которая возвращает x в степени n .
Иначе говоря, умножает x на себя n раз и возвращает результат. (пример:

```
pow(3, 2) = 3 * 3 = 9
pow(3, 3) = 3 * 3 * 3 = 27
pow(1, 100) = 1 * 1 * ...*1 = 1
```

)
Создайте страницу, которая запрашивает x и n , а затем выводит
результат pow(x,n) .
Запустить демо
P.S. В этой задаче функция обязана поддерживать только
натуральные значения n , т.е. целые от 1 и выше.
Вот решение

```
function pow(x, n) {
    var result = x;
    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        result *= x;
    }
    return result;
}
var x = prompt("x?", '');
var n = prompt("n?", '');
if (n <= 1) {
    alert('Степень ' + n +
        'не поддерживается, введите целую степень, большую 1'
        );
} else {
    alert( pow(x, n) );
}
```

Мне не понятно зачем нужна часть

> for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)

Без нее так же все работает как и с ней

Comment: По условию задачи 1 - это допустимое значение степени, а приведенный код его не пропустит.

Comment: Можно сделать оператором `**`.

Comment: «Без нее так же все работает» —эм, или я чего-то не понимаю, или без неё ничего не может работать. Покажите код, который без этой части и при этом работает

Comment: Не работает без цикла, сделайте очистку кеша  Ctrl+f5 если в Хроме.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта часть цикл который умножает result на x, n раз 
Без неё же, это будет простое возведение в квадрат

Comment: нашел такой вариант   function pow(x, n) {return x**n} .Кажется все работает так же.Или нет?

Comment: Да, операция ** возводит x в степень n
Вопрос в том какое решение нужно вам, если это чисто для развития алгоритм. мышления и тренировки, то первый вариант подходит лучше всего. А если чисто для удобства, то рациональнее использовать **

Answer (score -1):

Рекурсия приводит к хранению всех данных для неоконченных внешних вызовов в стеке, в данном случае это приводит к тому, что возведение в степень n хранит в памяти n различных контекстов. Реализация возведения в степень через цикл гораздо более экономна. У такой функции pow будет один контекст, в котором будут последовательно меняться значения i и result.

Comment: а где тут рекурсия?